# We want to give an outside party access to a demo environment. How do we ensure only they get access to only their version of the environment?

Tags: authorization

We are currently setting up a system where we can create demo environments for prospective clients to use, where we host those demo environments in our own DMZ. The idea is that if a prospect wants to try our product, we create an environment for them, then make it so only that prospect can access that environment.

Some details:

- The environment is CentOS 7;
- The product consists of 2 environment-hosted GUIs, supported by a number of services that also run in the environment;
- The prospect should have mostly full access to the environment (not root, but things like interacting with the file system, making changes to some of the software);
- We will have a separate environment per prospect and a prospect should only be able to access one environment.

This system is intended to mostly replace our current error prone and labour intensive process of helping the prospect setup the system on their local network.

The problem we have is that we need to give the prospect access to the environment over the Internet, but in such a way that only they can only access that particular environment they are assigned to. We don't want someone other than the prospect accessing the prospect's environment, and we don't want the prospect accessing another prospect's environment, and DEFINITELY not other machines in our DMZ.

Our current idea to solve this is by using private key authentication, which from what we gather is the proper way to allow only a single party access. However, we still need a secure way to get the key file to the prospect, who often is too far away to hand it over in person.

so 2 questions:

1. Is there a secure way to provide a prospect with a key file if you can't hand it over in person?
2. related: is key file based authentication the best way to grant a single client access to a single system?

Comment: How do you ensure that your non-demo environment customers can't access other environments?

Comment: You need an authorisation mechanism .... You are trying to 'authorise' by token (possession of a key), which is an authorisation by inference.

Answer (score 2):

You could virtualize the whole thing, create a virtual network for a single demo environment and deploy an environment on a per user basis. You can then indeed use key based authentication for accessing the environment. After the user has reviewed the demo you destroy the environment.

Your automation, if done properly, should be able to fully build, deploy, generate  key files and then send them to your client.

Normally this works is a bit differently. The client would supply you with their public SSH key and you would add this key to your machine in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a layer in front of the whole thing that performs authentication and authorisation. The user is authenticated and then authorised to access whatever environment. You control which environment from this layer.

From a technical perspective, I've done this by implementing [Apache Guacamole](http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/). Users are authenticated using the Guacamole database and the system authorises connection to the various systems with keys held by Guacamole (users never see the keys).

Even if you don't use Guacamole, this is the sort of thing you are looking to implement.